# Is a sum of Brownian motions a Gaussian process?

Tags: normal-distribution, brownian-motion

I was wondering whether the following sum of a Brownian motion $\{W_t, t\geq 0\}$ is also a Gaussian Process:
$$
X_t:= W_t +W_{t/2}
$$
**My attempt:**

Choose $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ randomly, if we can show $v_1X_{t_1}+\ldots+v_nX_{t_n}$ is normally distributed, we are done and know that $X_t$ is a Gaussian Process.

To show this, we want to rewrite $v_1X_{t_1}+\ldots+v_nX_{t_n}$ as some sum of independent increments of the Brownian Motion $W_t$, since we know that the sum of independent normals is once again normal.

Note that the set of all points for which we evaluate $W_t$ will be: $\{t_{1/2},t_1,t_{3/2},\ldots,t_{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor},t_{n/2},t_{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor+1},\ldots,t_{n-1},t_n\}$. Thus you can just rewrite the sum $v_1X_{t_1}+\ldots+v_nX_{t_n}$ as the sum of independent normals and therefore it is distributed normally and $X_t$ is a Gaussian process.

**Thoughts**

Is my approach correct? I feel as if I am missing something and my result is not correct. Is there a better way of approaching questions with regard to whether some transformation of Brownian Motions is a Gaussian Process?

Comment: Your idea is correct. All linear combinations of jointly normal variables are normal and so are joint distributions of several such linear combinations.

Comment: @peacefulbreeze This shows only that $X_t$ is Gaussian for each fixed $t>0$. Note that the OP needs to show that $(X_t)_t$ is a Gaussian process (i.e. that all the finite-dimensional distributions are Gaussian).

Answer (score 2):

If you know that Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Gaussian process, i.e. that $\sum_{j=1}^m c_j W_{s_j}$ is Gaussian for any $c_j \in \mathbb{R}$ and $s_1,\ldots,s_m>0$, then there is an easier way to prove the assertion:

Take $0<t_1 < \ldots<t_n$ and $d_1,\ldots,d_n \in \mathbb{R}$, then

$$\sum_{j=1}^n d_j X_{t_j} = \sum_{j=1}^n d_j W_{t_j} + \sum_{j=1}^n d_j W_{t_j/2}. \tag{1}$$

By renaming/-labeling, we can write the sum on the right-hand side in the form $\sum_{j=1}^{2n} c_j W_{s_j}$ for suitable coefficients $c_j$ and times $s_j>0$. Since $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Gaussian process, it thus follows that the right-hand side (hence, also the left-hand side) of $(1)$ is Gaussian.

Comment: Why is the sum of Gaussian processes also a Gaussian process? That seems like something that does not necessarily hold in general right?

Comment: @K.Kamal  The sum $(X_t+Y_t)_t$ of two different Gaussian processes need not be Gaussian, no. But here the situation is different because we are dealing with just one process... this allows us to write the right-hand side of $(1)$ in terms of sums of our original process $(W_t)_t$

Comment: do you perhaps have an example of some process that is distributed normally but is not Gaussian?

Comment: @K.Kamal Not sure whether I understand your question correctly. You are asking for a stochastic process $(X_t)_t$ such that $X_t$ is normally distributed for each $t$ but $(X_t)_t$ is not a Gaussian process... is that correct?